How to get v4l2loopback to work on Android, emulate webcam?

Several weeks, like WhatsApp web, 2chat API etc., Require one to scan a barcode on another device to active it.
To get around this on an Android one should be able to make a virtual webcam that is really a video of the qr code
Several questions on the Android stack exchange led to the library v4l2loopback, but in the docs I couldn't figure out yet how to get it to work for Android devices.
How can I use the v4l2loopback lifeway for Android?
No answer:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145020/how-to-emulate-camera-input-in-android-to-activate-whatsapp-web
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110505/creating-fake-microphone-and-camera-inputs-on-an-android-mobile
On that latter question there is a comment, that lead me here:

This kernel module looks relevant (github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback)

It doesn't seem like it was ever compiled for Android at the moment, but since Android is Linux based it would be possible.

I can't find any information that v4l2 is at all used by the Android environment, just pretty vague speculation by a single user, who also states that he's not sure it applies, so you might want to research whether this is true at all before continuing down this road. If you find definite confirmation that Android's camera system uses v4l2 under the hood: Are you able to compile, and more importantly, load any kernel module on your phone? What's the kernel version of your phone? Does v4l2loopback exist for that version?

@MarcusMüller yeah it was just that user. I don't know where else to look other than here for information on that

Maybe ask on the Android stackexchange site specifically whether V4l2 is what android does between camera and apps that use the camera?

@MarcusMüller already 3 questions on the subject with no answers after years

I'm afraid we're really not too many Android experts here: GNU/Linux or BSD-userland/Linux systems, sure, you'll find experts here. AOSP/Bionic/Linux Kernel that makes Android, not so much :(
